# My prefix has a classy house

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, affix-riddle

> My prefix has a classy house, where no one lives.
>
> My infix is a sneaky vermin.
>
> My suffix is the past of consumption.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could be

> OPERATE

My prefix has a classy house where nobody lives

> An Opera House is a classy house where nobody lives

My infix is a sneaky vermin

> A sneaky Rat.

My suffix is the past of consumption

> Consumption = Eat, whose past tense is Ate.

Comment: So close, but not quite

Comment: @gabbo1092 have any of my shots in the dark hit something?

Comment: keep trying though

Comment: Update #2 coming at you, @gabbo1092!